# create table with IDs for all arcs downstream of all others

Tags: arcgis-10.1, nhd, trace

I need to summarize downstream information associated with each arc in an NHD dataset.  I have a table with the downstream ID for stream segment but am not sure how to get all of the downstream IDs.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using NHDPlus? If you can deal with 1:100k data (instead of the high-res 1:24k NHD), the Value Added Attribute tables of NHDPlus allow for extremely rapid downstream navigation.

Comment: Have you seen RivEX (www.rivex.co.uk) it can generate an adjacency table which you use to traverse upstream or downstream?